# Can I manually override google optimize redirect, and avoid external redirect?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-redux, single-page-application, google-optimize

I'm running A/B redirect tests with Google optimize, using SPA on React, Redux platform.

A problem I'm trying to solve is - redirecting to the new page causes the full page reload, which I would like to avoid and rather prefer to do it manually, so it would be seamless for a user and much faster.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: was looking for a way to solve this problem as well. Still unresolved. But mb, this guide will be helpful: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-server-side

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a three years old question, maybe there are still users like me have the same issue.

Now Google has provided `Activation events` to [resolve dynamic websites and single-page apps reload issue](https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/7008840?hl=en).

> By default, Optimize modifies the content of a webpage only during its initial load. However, dynamic websites (built with tools like AMP, React, Angular, etc.) and single-page apps (SPA) commonly load additional content long after the initial page load. Optimize supports modifying this late-appearing web content via activation events.